# Find method on embedded document is returning null in symfony mongo

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-odm

I am new to symfony and creating project using mongodb as database. I am using embedded document in order to achieve multi-level database. Below are two document files I am using:
**Documents:**

```
namespace AppBundle\Document;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document()
 */
class State
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id()
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
     */
    protected $code;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\EmbedMany(targetDocument="City")
     */
    protected $cities = array();

    /**
     * State constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cities = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $id
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $name
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCode()
    {
        return $this->code;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $code
     */
    public function setCode($code)
    {
        $this->code = $code;
    }

    /**
     * @return City[]
     */
    public function getCities()
    {
        return $this->cities;
    }

    /**
     * @param City $city
     */
    public function addCities(City $city)
    {
        $this->cities[] = $city;
    }
} 

/**
 * @MongoDB\EmbeddedDocument()
 */
class City
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $id
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $name
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

}
```

I am properly able to add data to database and preview of it displayed below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59783f79d6faef0dc13cc8ce"),
    "name" : "New South Wales",
    "code" : "NSW",
    "cities" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59783f79d6faef0dc13cc8cf"),
            "name" : "Sydney"
        }
    ]
}
```

And now I am getting data using method "find()" with it's id:

```
$city = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')
->getManager()
->getRepository('AppBundle:City')
->find("59783f79d6faef0dc13cc8cf");
```

So, Problem here is:

> I am receiving **null** in $city. How can I get details of city like name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mapped `City` as an embedded document thus it can't exist without its parent document. The only way you can get it is fetching the `State` and then iterating through `$state->getCities()`. If you need to query for cities, you need references so `City` would become a first class document with its own collection Mongo can scan.

Comment: So, Is it possible to find parent "State" details from available id of city using document manager?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to employ Query Builder and read about [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)